# Where to publish a critical comment on an academic paper?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, communication

#### Background

Last year, in October, an exceptionally weak paper [was published in Nature](https://doi.org/10.1038/nature19793). The publication of such a piece in a top journal [was a clear violation](https://www.nrc.nl/nieuws/2016/12/09/how-weak-science-slipped-past-through-review-and-landed-in-a-top-journal-a1535637) of peer-review standards. Despite the title and publication in a reputable journal, this paper did not provide any evidence.

#### My attempts

I guess, I was the first to submit a [Brief Communication Arising](http://www.nature.com/nature/authors/gta/commsarising.html) to Nature just a week after the initial publication. My comment was rejected two weeks later, and I [published it in Publons system](https://dx.doi.org/10.14322/publons.r505407). I see that up until now there has been no clear statement in the peer-reviewed academic literature of the flawed nature of Dong et al paper.

#### The question

What is the best way to publish a critical comment on a paper published in top journal, if that journal rejected the comment?

*I believe, it is very important to publish the critical comment in a peer-reviewed journal. However, usually journals are only willing to consider critical comments on the papers published in their pages.*

Comment: Was there any reason given for the rejection of your response?

Comment: Yes, but it was not very clear. First, the editor mentioned that there is a high "competition in this section of the journal". Second, she noted that, to her view, my comment "...would not add to our understanding or otherwise clarify the issues for our readers". 
  
I dare say, the second is not correct.

Comment: I think you have published your response on a suitable place (Publons).  If the journal themselves won't publish it, there is little other choice (I could be wrong) - I am just reading your letter and the rebuttal from one of the authors.

Comment: It would be nice if in this day and age all journals would provide an online venue for discussion of their own articles.  I think USENIX started doing this for their conferences a while back.  But in this case, I agree with @Saturnus, looks like OP took the path available and should leave it there.

Comment: Yes, I am happy with Publons - it's a nice platform. But the thing is, it seems, in academia only peer-reviewed pieces are valued.

Comment: Valued for what? Do you want to publish this because you think it is important for people to know, or because you need publications on your CV?

Comment: @Tobias do you often see academic papers citing not peer-reviewed texts? In this context, I want my comment to be viewed as a part of academic literature. This way it will be known to the relevant audience

Comment: @ikashnitsky For your work to be peer-reviewed, it seems, it will have take a form of an independent paper, rather than a comment to an existing one. In particular, it seems, it should assert something (this is the data, this is our model, this is our conclusion) rather than refute (this is the data, this is a model, this model is bad).

Comment: @AlexeyB. I offer a fresh explanation why the data on maximal lifespans in the recent years seemed to hit a ceiling. We are working on a bigger separate paper; but meanwhile I would like to frame this comment as an academically recognized piece

Comment: *She noted that, to her view, my comment "...would not add to our understanding or otherwise clarify the issues for our readers".*  I wonder if you could strengthen your comment and re-submit?  Also, I wonder if you could request more detailed feedback?

Comment: @FredDouglis the Nature page of the article does have a comment section, with currently only one comment.

Comment: @aparente001 I did ask for a more detailed feedback but received no answer for my email. It did not sound like the re-submission was welcome. Anyways, I said what I had to say. The only way I saw to "improve" my comment was to ask some senior colleague to be a co-author upon re-submission. And that's not what I wanted to do.

Comment: @ikashnitsky - Could you ask a more senior colleague for feedback on your manuscript, without actually co-authoring?

Comment: Just for the record: the paper has already a handful of brief comments published in Nature, so  if OP is one of them, congratulations, if not, maybe the editor was correct limiting the number of these comments, and OP may better shoot for a full paper (if she/he say more to say than the already published comments / critiques of the paper)

Answer (score 7):

> Do you know what is the best way to publish a critical comment on a paper published in top journal if that journal rejected the comment?

In another top journal. But your comment "have take a form of an independent paper" as [Alexey](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/52615/alexey-b) wrote.

Check those two examples from Computer Science field. First ([1](https://doi.org/10.1145/2568225.2568324)) from ICSE, Software Engineering community top venue, where Monperrus offers a critical review on others' paper. Second ([2](http://doi.org/10.1002/asi.23756)), Arapakis et al. challenge the results reported in Bandari et al.

In my opinion, you should go for a peer-reviewed paper, which is a very noble form of scientific debate.

Answer (score 5):

- place to start could be [PubPeer](https://pubpeer.com/).  It's not exactly what you want but, quoting Wikipedia:

> (t)he site is one of many allowing academics to engage in post-publication peer review, and has highlighted shortcomings in several high-profile papers, in some cases leading to retractions and to accusations of scientific fraud, as noted by Retraction Watch.

Comment: [Done](https://pubpeer.com/publications/48DAAE1F561C62D32E477F193462E4) long ago. That's not the point of my question

Comment: @ikashnitsky, why do you insist on publishing your critical comment in a peer-reviewed outlet? PubPeer is still a good place for such flagging purposes.